# How to tell how exposed to extraterritorial USA sanctions my EU bank is?

Tags: united-states, banking, regulation, sepa, sanctions

The USA [have threatened extraterritorial financial sanctions](http://foreignpolicy.com/2018/02/20/europes-iran-deal-threats-are-empty-trump-iran-eu/) for EU entities which do business with Iran (see the link for how it works and further resources, including relevant USA laws). The EU's proposed countermeasures [will be announced](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_SPEECH-18-3830_fr.htm) tomorrow.

Suppose I'm an EU person or entity, I don't have any business in USA and I only or mostly conduct transactions in Euro.

To minimise the risk of disruption, I'd like to gradually move my and my customers' transactions, assets, credit lines etc. to whichever of my banks is least exposed to sanctions. What factors should I check?

I've thought of checking whether my bank has:

- any USA subsidiary or participation;
- accounts in USD;
- security accounts which trade in USA exchanges;
- specific services for USD/EUR conversion or other currency services which might go through private entities in USA.

I've checked the BIS (Bank of International Settlements) and I found some information on the mechanisms and amounts at play, but no bank-specific information: [Non-US banks' claims on the Federal Reserve](https://www.bis.org/publ/qtrpdf/r_qt1403i.htm); [Distinguishing global dollar reserves from official holdings in the United States](https://www.bis.org/publ/qtrpdf/r_qt0509e.pdf).

Comment: Cf. https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-iran-nuclear-france-total/frances-total-will-quit-iran-gas-project-if-no-sanctions-waiver-idUKKCN1IH1XU?il=0

Comment: Does Europe not have an analogue to our FDIC? Cause frankly, i wouldn't care if the rest of the world levied sanctions against my bank -- my money's covered.

Comment: @cHao deposites are insured up to 100 k€ per account, but that's really not the problem.

Comment: So what kind of "disruption" are you worried about? And why aren't you asking about business in/with Iran too (which is the one thing that would trigger sanctions in the first place)?

Comment: @cHao There is more information about extraterritorial sanctions on the first article I linked. This question is about how to choose an EU bank to follow EU law in EU.

Comment: You're asking about banks that associate in any way with the US, not about banks that "follow EU law in EU" or any other such nonsense. If the latter is what you want, you're going to have to explain what you mean by it, or at least how some however-vague association with the US has anything to do with it. Cause right now it looks like you are confused about the extent of the sanctions and/or are simply posturing.

Comment: Looks like SWIFT is indeed one of the biggest concerns: https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-iran-nuclear-germany/germany-urges-eu-payment-system-without-u-s-to-save-iran-deal-idUKKCN1L61KS

Comment: And is irrelevant to your question as written.

Comment: "Italian restaurant owner wrongly targeted by US sanctions" https://www.bbc.com/news/business-56611977
All his bank accounts were immediately blocked. https://www.ilpost.it/2021/04/02/sanzioni-stati-uniti-ristoratore-verona-alessandro-bazzoni/

Comment: I found there's a list of TARGET2 participants but I believe by definition those are all legally domiciled in the EU so it's hard to spot the USA subsidiaries. https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/target/target2/profuse/participation/html/index.en.html

Answer (score 1):

Stick to local credit unions and small banks. Large Banks generally have global presence in some form and shape.

Even if worst things happen, the Banks in Europe will loose Banking license in US, meaning they will have quite a bit of assets frozen or may take a while to get back ... this can cause financial hardship to the EU Banks, however if there is a collapse of EU Banks in such situation; the EU Central Bank will step in and provide some relief.

In short; this shouldn't affect individuals or small business much.

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't know. Apparently a source of concern is «access to the SWIFT international bank payments messaging system» (Reuters: https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-iran-nuclear-talks/iran-pressures-europe-to-speed-up-plans-to-save-nuclear-deal-idUKKCN1IQ00C). Even small banks need SWIFT, don't they? Are they safe in case SWIFT is targeted?

Comment: Nobody can afford to have SWIFT shut down. And it isn't a bank, it's a service. Though if your credit union is running some of it's money/data through another bank that might be a vulnerability. But if it is, I'm not sure there's anything constructive you can do about it.